# Migrating intellisense from Visual Studio 2015 to VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Hi,

In VS2015 I had excellent intellisense support through the use of intellisense.js reference files dotted through out the project. These combined with JsDoc notation ensured that all my non-library code had intellisense support.

[image]

```
/// <reference path="hudtimer.js" />
/// <reference path="intellisense.js" />
/// <reference path="menulayergametimers.js" />
/// <reference path="menulayerstreakidentifier.js" />
/// <reference path="streakidentifier.js" />
/// <reference path="menulayerpop.js" />
/// <reference path="popentity.js" />
/// <reference path="popentityfactory.js" />
/// <reference path="popactions.js" />
/// <reference path="menulayerpophud.js" />
/// <reference path="popquestion.js" />
/// <reference path="popcharacter.js" />
/// <reference path="popvfxmanager.js" />
```

In VSCode, these files are essentially ignored which results in very poor intellisense. It seems to prefer TypeScript definitions, which is not something I've really looked into before and could potentially consume an enormous amount of time to create/generate for each file in the code base (big project!)

Is there a way to force/coax VSCode into using the already set-up intellisense.js files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) file at the root of your project with the contents:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

This file should ensure that all js file in your workspace—including `intellisense.js`—are picked up and included in the same JavaScript project.

In the future, I also recommend you try to migrate away from using a `reference` paths file to using the `jsconfig` to define your project structure

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. This is a much better solution then relying on reference paths. We will definitely be using this going forward